# reference a local variable from string

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way that I could represent a local variable name by passing a string to represent the variable name?
for example something like this

```
val arr1 = arrayOf(1,2,3,"Apple")
val arr2: Array<Int> = Array(6,{i -> i * 2})
val arr3: Array<Int> = Array<Int>(6,{i -> i+1})
val arr4 = arrayOf<Int>(1,2,3)
for (i in 1..4){
    val arrResult = java.util.Arrays.deepToString("arr${i}")
    println(arrResult)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Such question usually means that you want to use dictionaries. In this case an array suffices:

```
fun main() {
    val arr0 = arrayOf(1,2,3,"Apple")
    val arr1: Array<Int> = Array(6,{i -> i * 2})
    val arr2: Array<Int> = Array<Int>(6,{i -> i+1})
    val arr3 = arrayOf<Int>(1,2,3)
    val arrs = arrayOf(arr0, arr1, arr2, arr3)
    for (i in 0..3) {
        val arrResult = java.util.Arrays.deepToString(arrs[i])
        println(arrResult)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer and definitely helps 

Comment: Agreed.  (The direct answer to this question would be to use reflection, but in my experience that's only needed for built tools, plug-ins, testing, &c — in general application code there's almost always a better approach.)